# How to share custom video to Facebook from iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, video, share

I'm developing iOS app that works with video.
I need to share custom video to Facebook - post it to wall.

Here is how video player should look like inside Facebook post: 
http://monosnap.com/image/XhXhbpJV0qYSpgeGVw3SBQPZ6qOPt2

As you can see - there are a lot of customization - user avatar, app logo, custom play button, gradient overlay, video stats.

Please help - Is it possible to implement, and if 'yes' - how?

Comment: There's no way to specify the type of customizations you want for a video uploaded to FB.

Comment: It is not possible. I was searching the ways to implement custom video player for Facebook post.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you won't have control over the exact layout, most of the data you want (title, description, call to action) is available to be posted to Facebook [using the graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video)

That's likely as close as you'll get. For the custom play button, you could try uploading a thumbnail image along with the video, to be displayed before the play button is pressed.